# How to build a link to a field_ui form?

Tags: 8, entities, routes

Given an entity type id of a fieldable entity type, a bundle name, and a view mode name, how do I construct a url to the respective field_ui form where this view mode can be edited?

The patterns for the route name seem to be:

- `entity.entity_view_display.ENTITY_TYPE_ID.view_mode`
- `entity.entity_view_display.ENTITY_TYPE_ID.default`

But it seems the parameters have custom names, e.g. `/admin/structure/types/manage/{node_type}/display/{view_mode_name}`, here the bundle parameter is called `node_type`.

Is there a generic way to build such urls to field_ui pages for any entity type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching in the core files I found the pattern, see the example below:

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
// The entity type can be 'node'.
$entity_type = 'taxonomy_term';

// Find the bundle entity type, e.g. 'node_type' or .
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $etm */
$etm = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager');
$bundle_entity_type = $etm->getDefinition($entity_type)->getBundleEntityType();

if (NULL === $bundle_entity_type) {
  // Not clear what to do in this case.
  return NULL;
}

// The bundle can be 'article'.
$bundle = 'tags';
// The route, see that the $entity_type variable is used.
$route = "entity.entity_view_display.$entity_type.view_mode";
// The view mode can be 'teaser'.
$view_mode = 'full';
$a = Url::fromRoute($route, [$bundle_entity_type => $bundle, 'view_mode_name' => $view_mode])->toString();
// To use dpm() you need the Devel module.
dpm($a);
```

Comment: But what is the generic way to find `$bundle_entity_type`?

Comment: I think that this is another question like: How to find all the existing bundle entity types? Your question here is *Is there a generic way to build such urls to field_ui pages for any entity type?* I think that is better if you create another question, if you do it let my know.

Comment: Sorry but without this part, the answer is incomplete. It only shows how to build such urls for taxonomy terms. But I agree that "How to find all the existing bundle entity types?" is a worthwhile question by itself.

Comment: @donquixote if you use the values that I write in the comments you will see that this code works for all the entities, just check again and try for nodes.

Comment: It seems that `$bundleEntityTypeId = $targetEntityType->getBundleEntityType();` provides what we need.

Comment: @donquixote feel free to edit my answer ;-)

Comment: Done. But I wonder if really every entity type with bundles also has a bundle entity type?

Comment: @donquixote all the entity content will have it.

Comment: @donquixote at the end do you solve your problem?

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to accept :)